# The preview of the post doesn't match how the post is rendered when saved

Tags: bug, status-completed, markdown

In [Why the "meat" in "sweetmeat"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/39578/why-the-meat-in-sweetmeat) [my answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/revisions/39623/1) appears different in the preview from where it appears in when saved.

[image: screenshot]

[image: screenshot]

Is it supposed to be so, or is there a bug laughing behind my shoulders?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is [fixed in the next build](http://code.google.com/p/markdownsharp/source/detail?r=ecb29dd6bb5085859aa056649537a0003de39bb4).

For the curious: The preview's behavior was the correct one, since this:

```
1. abc
<!-- comment -->

2. def
```

is equivalent to this:

```
1. abc <!-- comment -->

2. def
```

(to be considered a "block level HTML comment", the comment must be preceded by a blank line). The preview did this correctly; the server-side version had a bug that considered it enough for the comment to start at the beginning of the line.